# NGINX - Adding a suffix to static file location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am using nginx to server static image files. Within my directory, all images are stored with an extension _.txt (basically renamed to *.txt). For example: background.png will be stored as background.png*.txt

How do I redirect the lookup for domain.com/images/background.png to look for /static/images/background.png_.txt

Here is my nginx config so far...

```
    location /images/  {
        alias    /static/images/;
        access_log off;
    }
```

Comment: Do all images have that extension or just .png? Also, are you expecting the browser to load it as .txt, or have some dynamic change happen to convert it back to an image?

Comment: @Bman70 Yes all images are stored with same extension "_.txt" (just renamed). I want the browser to display it as an image.

Comment: If your images weren't renamed, the server finds them correctly, is that right? If it's like my server, it already looks in `static` to find the images folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my server. It just takes the request for something in the images directory and checks if it exists, then checks if it exists with the `.txt` extension, and finally gives a 404 error if those aren't found.

```
location /images/ {
default_type "image/gif";
try_files $uri $uri.txt $uri =404;
}
```

Just make sure you don't duplicate the `location/images` block. Add it if it's not there, but it should be already, so just add the `try_files` line to it.

As I wrote in a comment, I'd be surprised if your server doesn't already search in `static` when going to the images directory. However, if the code I shared doesn't work, you could add the path for your modified image files to the block, e.g.:

```
location /images/ {
root /home/username/path_to_site/domain.com/static/images;
default_type "image/gif";
try_files $uri $uri.txt $uri =404;
}
```

**Edit**
If you examine the response headers, some browsers show images served this way as `content-type:text/plain`. One hack to override this is to specify types directly in the images location block:

```
location /images/ {
default_type "image/gif";
try_files $uri $uri.txt $uri =404;
types {
    text/plain    gif;
    image/jpg     jpeg jpg;
    image/png     png;
    image/gif     gif;
    image/x-icon  ico;
 }
}
```

These types are defined elsewhere in nginx, but this is easier if you don't want to do surgery in the guts of your server. The important line is `text/plain    gif;`. This is defining any text files found in the images directory as `image/gif`.

Final thoughts: This might be better done as a [**rewrite**](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/), however maybe someone else knows the details of that method.

Comment: Nice, it mostly works except the Content-Type header. Setting default_type "image/gif" does not work. I checked chrome response header and it shows "Plain/Text", any suggestions?

Comment: That is interesting, Firefox shows the header content type as `text/plain` too. It still serves images fine, so it's only cosmetic. I'll edit the answer to show a way to make it show an image type instead.

Comment: Thank you. Setting {text/plain    gif;} worked. I'll mark your answer as accepted. FYI, based on your comment about using rewrite, I was tinkering with it and got it to work. But your method seems to be simpler.